# adding a printer through PowerShell doesn't allow me to print but adding it though control panel will

Tags: powershell, printing

I'm trying to test adding printers through PowerShell and I've had 1 successful test by adding a printer already added to the pc through PowerShell by removing the printer through control panel then running the PowerShell script:
`Add-Printer -Name "Xerox WorkCentre 6605DN V4 PCL6" -DriverName "Xerox WorkCentre 6605DN V4 PCL6" -PortName "192.168.0.80"`
then i varied the code for the new printer:

`Add-Printer -Name "Brother MFC-L5750DW series Printer" -DriverName "Microsoft IPP Class Driver" -PortName "192.168.0.141"`
but when I've tried it from a brand new printer that wasn't already added to the computer it doesn't work I have run both the `add-printerport 192.168.0.141` and `add-printerdriver "Microsoft IPP Class Driver"` and those seemed to work but whenever I add the printer with the script and try and print a test page it appears in the print queue for less than a second and nothing comes out but, when I remove it and add the printer through control panel it allows me to print test pages no problem I've looked through the settings and it has all the same setting as when I added it through PowerShell, The computer is on the same network as the the printer and the printer port is the same both times 

I'm not sure what to try to fix this

I've re-asked this question on stack exchange superuser please answer there if you have an answer

Comment: you might have better luck getting this answered on superuser.com

Comment: Out of curiousity.. What happens if you restart the print spooler service after installing the new pronter? `Restart-Service -Name Spooler`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out why it wasn't working, the port name was somehow screwing up(or that's as much as I can assume) so instead of:

```
add-printerport 192.168.0.141
```

I used:

```
add-printerport -name "bp" -printerhostaddress "192.168.0.141"
```

than added the printer with the new port name of "bp" and it prints correctly now i also used a different built in Microsoft driver "Microsoft PCL6 Class Driver" which may be a reason for success